# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Issue' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

Apologies, but PHP isn't exactly my strong point. I'm getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Issue' (T_STRING) whenever I fill out a particular form. The error in questions is occurring on line 27.

```
<?php
      $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
      $details = $_REQUEST['details'] ;
      $action = $_REQUEST['action'] ;
      $corporate = $_REQUEST['corporate'] ;
      $techSupervisor = $_REQUEST['techSupervisor'] ;



      $message = 
      "Issue Report Submitted from Mr. Rekey Website 

      Person Reporting: $name

      Details of Issue:
      $details

      Action Taken:
      $action

      Additional Follow Up:
      Corporate: $corporate
      Technician Supervisor: $techSupervisor" ;

      $message2 = 
      "" ;
        mail( "michaelwhite@rekey.com, ken@rekey.com, josh@rekey.com, eli@rekey.com, krissy@rekey.com, ben@rekey.com, dan@rekey.com, geraldatl@gmail.com, scott@rekeycommercial.com, barrygreenwald@rekey.com, barrylivingston@rekey.com, billsteiner@rekey.com, damonhoover@rekey.com, daniel@rekey.com, dkern@rekey.com, edwardthomas@rekey.com, julievargas@rekey.com, khalidmiller@rekey.com, markloden@rekey.com, peteharrison@rekey.com, peterhernandez@rekey.com, russelldickerson@rekey.com,jamie@rekey.com, "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "denny@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "ken@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "eli@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "josh@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "krissy@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "ben@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "dan@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "pj@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "issues@rekey.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "geraldatl@gmail.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "scott@rekeycommercial.com", "Issue Reported", $message, "From: Rekey.com" );
      // mail( "keyorders@rekey.com", "Order - key order", $message, "From: $email" );
      // mail( "eli@rekey.com", "Order - key order", $message, "From: $email" );
      // mail( $email, "Key Order Received", $message2, "From: orders@rekey.com" );
      header( "Location: report-issue-thankyou.html" );
    ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the "mail" parameter, see that after the last email you forgot a **"** (quote)

Comment: Look at the colors...